# R: Error when setting colors for multiple plots using ggplot2 and marrangeGrob

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I need to make a lot of plots of drug concentration over the course of time for various subjects in a study, and I'd like to consistently set the color based on what drug they've taken. Not all patients are taking the same drugs, though. Here is what I've tried:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

A <- data.frame(Time = seq(0, 20, 5),
            DrugConcentration = 100*exp(-0.25*seq(0, 20, 5)),
            Drug = "Midazolam")

B <- data.frame(Time = rep(seq(0, 20, 5), 2),
                DrugConcentration = c(100*exp(-0.25*seq(0, 20, 5)),
                                      75*exp(-0.1*seq(0, 20, 5))),
                Drug = rep(c("Midazolam", "Dextromethorphan"), each = 5))

C <- data.frame(Time = rep(seq(0, 20, 5), 3),
                DrugConcentration = c(100*exp(-0.25*seq(0, 20, 5)),
                                      75*exp(-0.1*seq(0, 20, 5)),
                                      50*exp(-0.15*seq(0, 20, 5))),
                Drug = rep(c("Midazolam", "Dextromethorphan", "Tolbutamide"), 
                           each = 5))

D <- data.frame(Time = rep(seq(0, 20, 5), 2),
                DrugConcentration = c(100*exp(-0.25*seq(0, 20, 5)),
                                      50*exp(-0.15*seq(0, 20, 5))),
                Drug = rep(c("Midazolam", "Tolbutamide"), 
                           each = 5))

DrugList <- list(A, B, C, D)

MyColors <- data.frame(Drug = c("Midazolam", "Dextromethorphan", "Tolbutamide"),
                       Color = c("red", "green", "blue"),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

PlotList <- list()

for(i in 1:length(DrugList)){
      DrugList[[i]] <- arrange(DrugList[[i]], Drug, Time)
      MyColors.temp <- join(DrugList[[i]][, c("Drug", "Time")], 
                        MyColors, by = "Drug")
      MyColors.temp <- unique(MyColors.temp[, c("Drug", "Color")])
      MyColors.temp <- arrange(MyColors.temp, Drug)

      PlotList[[i]] <- 
          ggplot(DrugList[[i]], 
               aes(x = Time, y = DrugConcentration, 
                   color = Drug)) +
          geom_point() + geom_line() +
          scale_color_manual(values = MyColors.temp$Color)
}
```

The loop runs, but when I try

```
marrangeGrob(PlotList, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

I get the error: `Insufficient values in manual scale. 3 needed but only 2 provided.` If I look at each plot individually, e.g., by typing `PlotList[[1]]`, the first two plots will at least generate plots (although the colors are not consistent for each drug and not what I specified), but the third is the one that gives me that error about not having enough values.

Here is the 1st plot, with the correct color for midazolam: [image: concentration time curve midazolam]

And here is the 2nd plot, which does not have the correct colors: [image: concentration time curve midazolam dextromethorphan]

What's going on here? Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why isn't this working?*

plot 3 is the problem – not by itself, but in combination with the for loop and ggplot2's lazy evaluation mechanism. When you're defining each plot, ggplot2 captures correctly the environment for the i-th dataset, but the manual scale is stored as an unevaluated promise. When it's eventually evaluated (when ggplot_build is called shortly before drawing), `MyColors.temp` only has two values (the latest iteration of the loop), and plot 3 complains that the manual scale is provided with too few values.

*Why is the colour scale inconsistent?*

`scale_colour_manual` requires a named vector, not a pair of values–breaks (it certainly fooled me until I read the help page!).

There are a few possible solutions.

#### Passing the whole set of colours as named vector

```
MyColors <- c("Midazolam" = "red", "Dextromethorphan" = "green", "Tolbutamide" = "blue")

DrugList <- list(A, B, C, D)

PlotList <- list()

for(i in 1:length(DrugList)){

  PlotList[[i]] <- 
    ggplot(arrange(DrugList[[i]], Drug, Time), 
           aes(x = Time, y = DrugConcentration, 
               color = Drug)) +
    geom_point() + geom_line()  +
    scale_colour_manual(values = MyColors) +
    theme()
}

grid.arrange(grobs=PlotList)
```

[image]

#### Facetting

```
m <- reshape2::melt(DrugList, measure.vars = "DrugConcentration")
str(m)

p <- ggplot(m, aes(x = Time, y = value, color = Drug)) +
  facet_wrap(~L1) +
  geom_point() + geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = MyColors)
```

[image]

`ggforce` appears to provide a facetting function that can extend over multiple pages. It's also pretty easy to achieve with an extra dummy variable to split the entire dataset into groups to plot as individual 2x2 facets.

#### Split-apply

If you need separate plots, it's also easier to work with the long format data.frame,

```
lp <- plyr::dlply(m, "L1", function(d) p %+% d)

grid.arrange(grobs = lp)
```

[image]

Comment: Because I have about 8000 graphs that I'm going to need my poor undergraduate research assistant to pore over looking for possible data entry errors. I need lots of pages and I can't facet that many graphs.

Comment: IIRC there's a recent package that implements multi-page facets

Comment: A multi-page faceted graph solution would be fantastic!

Comment: Also, the 2nd set of graphs you show suffers from the same problem I'm having with not having consistent colors for each drug.

Comment: I'm working through your solution... What does this part do? `function(d) p %+% d`

Comment: `"%+%" ` is a ggplot2 function to update an existing plot with a new dataset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130818/discussion-between-lauras-and-baptiste).